# Android Instantiation error i.e Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i am trying to save parsed data into database but there's an instantiation exception. I am using Parcelable to pass parsed arraylist from one activity to another.I need to pass those arraylist from one activity to another and store it in sqlite.

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity implements Parcelable{
//private ScheduleClient scheduleClient;
public Calendar cal;
//TextView desciption1;
TextView name1;
    private GetData mGetData;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http address";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "group_header"; // parent node
static String KEY_NAME = "name";
static  String KEY_ID = "group_day";
static  String KEY_COST = "day_sun_mrg";
static String KEY_DESC = "day_sun_evn";
static final String KEY_COST1 = "day_mon_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC1 = "day_mon_evn";
static final String KEY_COST2 = "day_tue_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC2 = "day_tue_evn";
static final String KEY_COST3 = "day_wed_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC3 = "day_wed_evn";
static final String KEY_COST4 = "day_thu_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC4 = "day_thu_evn";
static final String KEY_COST5 = "day_fri_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC5 = "day_fri_evn";
static final String KEY_COST6 = "day_sat_mrg";
static final String KEY_DESC6 = "day_sat_evn";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// creating new HashMap
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e,   KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_COST,parser.getValue(e,  KEY_COST));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        map.put(KEY_COST1,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST1));
        map.put(KEY_DESC1, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC1));
        map.put(KEY_COST2,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST2));
        map.put(KEY_DESC2, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC2));
        map.put(KEY_COST3,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST3));
        map.put(KEY_DESC3, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC3));
        map.put(KEY_COST4,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST4));
        map.put(KEY_DESC4, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC4));
        map.put(KEY_COST5,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST5));
        map.put(KEY_DESC5, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC5));
        map.put(KEY_COST6,parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST6));
        map.put(KEY_DESC6, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC6));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);

        //Passing Data to Store Page
        mGetData.addLoad(menuItems);
        //putStringArrayListExtra(menuItems, ArrayList<String> menuItems);



}
    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
            R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);

            startActivity(in);


        }

    });
}

public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeString(KEY_NAME);
    dest.writeString(KEY_COST);
    dest.writeString(KEY_DESC);
}

public AndroidXMLParsingActivity(Parcel source){
    KEY_NAME=source.readString();
    KEY_COST=source.readString();
    KEY_DESC=source.readString();
    source.readArrayList(getClassLoader());
}
```

And my sqlite code is as follow [WORKS]

```
public class DBAdapter {

// Contacts Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "group_id";
private static final String KEY_SUNM = "sunm";
private static final String KEY_SUNE = "sune";
private static final String KEY_MONM = "monm";
private static final String KEY_MONE = "mone";
private static final String KEY_TUEM = "tuem";
private static final String KEY_TUEE = "tuee";
private static final String KEY_WEDM = "wedm";
private static final String KEY_WEDE = "wede";
private static final String KEY_THUM = "thum";
private static final String KEY_THUE = "thue";
private static final String KEY_FRIM = "frim";
private static final String KEY_FRIE = "frie";
private static final String KEY_SATM = "satm";
private static final String KEY_SATE = "sate";

AsyncTask sch;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_NAME";

// Contacts table name
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "TABLE_NAME";

// Database Version
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 // Creating Tables
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table if not exists TABLE_NAME (_id integer primary key autoincrement,group_id text,sunm text ,sune text ,monm text,mone text ,tuem text,tuee text,wedm text ,wede text ,thum text,thue text ,frim text ,frie text ,satm text,sate text )";

 private final Context context;

 private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;

 private static SQLiteDatabase db;

 public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
 {
      this.context = ctx;
      DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
 }

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
 {
     private static final String TAG = null;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
     {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
     {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);  
     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                 + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS schedules");
         onCreate(db);
     }
 }    

 //---opens the database---
 public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
 {
     db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     return this;
 }

 //---closes the database---    
 public void close() 
 {
     DBHelper.close();
 }

 //Inserting data into the table 
public void insertData(String group_id, String sunm, String sune, String monm, String mone, String tuem, String tuee, 
        String wedm, String wede, String thum, String thue, String frim, String frie, String satm, String sate) {
    try{
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schedules", null);
     if (cur!=null && cur.getCount() > 0){
         cur.moveToFirst();
         if (cur.getInt(0) <= 6) {//put in these statements contained in array
             Log.i("DB getCount", " getcount less than 0, should read array");//log message

             String insertQuery ="INSERT INTO schedules(group_id,sunm,sune,monm,mone,tuem,tuee,wedm,wede,thum,thue,frim,frie," +
                    "satm,sate)"+ "VALUES" + "("+"'"+group_id+"'"+","+"'"+sunm+"'"+","+"'"+sune+"'"+","+"'"+monm+"'"+"," +
                    ""+"'"+mone+"'"+","+"'"+tuem+"'"+","+"'"+tuee+"'"+","+"'"+wedm+"'"+","+"'"+wede+"'"+","+"'"+thum+"'"+"," +
                            ""+"'"+thue+"'"+","+"'"+frim+"'"+","+"'"+frie+"'"+","+"'"+satm+"'"+","+"'"+sate+"'"+")";
             db.execSQL(insertQuery);

             Log.e("a", ""+cur.getCount());
         }
     }
     else{
           //do nothing everything's as it should be
         Log.i("DB getCount", " getcount greater than 0");  //log message  
     }
     cur.close();
    db.close();

     }
    catch(SQLiteException e){System.err.println("Exception @ rawQuery: " + e.getMessage());}
}

  //---retrieves all the title--- 
 public Cursor getAllTitles() 
 {
     return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SUNM,KEY_SUNE,KEY_MONM,KEY_MONE,KEY_MONM,KEY_TUEM,
     KEY_TUEE,KEY_WEDM,KEY_WEDE,KEY_THUM,KEY_THUE,KEY_FRIM,KEY_FRIE,KEY_SATM,KEY_SATE}, null, null, null, null, null, null);         
 }

 //---retrieves a particular title---
public ScheduleItem getSelectedItem(String group){

 ScheduleItem schedule = new ScheduleItem();

    // Select All Query
    String searchQuery = "select * from schedules where group_id = '"+group+"'";
    Log.e("DBAdapter", group);
        try{
            //Database not open error
             Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);

         if (cur!=null && cur.getCount() > 0){
          cur.moveToFirst();
        //Setting DB value to model scheduleitem.java
          schedule.setName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("group_id")));
          schedule.setSunm(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sunm")));
          schedule.setSune(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sune")));
          schedule.setMonm(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("monm")));
          schedule.setMone(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("mone")));
          schedule.setTuem(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("tuem")));
          schedule.setTuee(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("tuee")));
          schedule.setWedm(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("wedm")));
          schedule.setWede(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("wede")));
          schedule.setThum(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("thum")));
          schedule.setThue(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("thue")));
          schedule.setFrim(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("frim")));
          schedule.setFrie(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("frie")));
          schedule.setSatm(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("satm")));
          schedule.setSate(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("sate")));
          }

         cur.close();
         db.close();
         return schedule;

         }catch(SQLiteException e){System.err.println("Exception @ rawQuery: " + e.getMessage());}
      return schedule;
     }

    public void scheduleupdate(){

        Log.e(DATABASE_NAME, "Data Removed");
        //String delQuery="DELETE FROM TABLE schedules";
        context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        //db.execSQL(delQuery);
        db.close();

    }
}
```

Help me
Logcat Error

```
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mokshya.multinodeparse/com.mokshya.multinodeparse.parse.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.mokshya.multinodeparse.parse.AndroidXMLParsingActivity
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
09-18 13:11:03.362: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  ... 11 more
com.mokshya.multinodeparse.parse.AndroidXMLParsingActivity
```

Comment: See your `CREATE_LOADS_TABLE`, you may need to take a note on the spaces. for example, after `KEY_SUN` you should put `" STRING, "` instead of `"STRING,"` (see the space).

Comment: OK there's no error i mean there's no space in original code. Thanks for suggestion anyway

Comment: @Aprian is correctly telling you that you *NEED* that space around " STRING, " in CREATE_LOADS_TABLE.  btw that could not be the only error in your code

Comment: @guido ahh ok and i know that there are other error which i have not been able to find that's why i am posting it

Comment: @Aprian i have done it but even same mistake resides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might help some newbie to tackle so i am posting my Answer. Here I have parsed the value and passed it to the sqlite from same function directly using AsyncTask. The code are as below:

```
public class LoadScheduleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

DBAdapter dba;

Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

// Connection Detector Class
ConnectionDetector cd;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// XML Parsing URL
static final String URL = "url address";

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "group_header"; // Parent Node
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_SUNM = "day_sun_mrg";
static final String KEY_SUNE = "day_sun_evn";
static final String KEY_MONM = "day_mon_mrg";
static final String KEY_MONE = "day_mon_evn";
static final String KEY_TUEM = "day_tue_mrg";
static final String KEY_TUEE = "day_tue_evn";
static final String KEY_WEDM = "day_wed_mrg";
static final String KEY_WEDE = "day_wed_evn";
static final String KEY_THUM = "day_thu_mrg";
static final String KEY_THUE = "day_thu_evn";
static final String KEY_FRIM = "day_fri_mrg";
static final String KEY_FRIE = "day_fri_evn";
static final String KEY_SATM = "day_sat_mrg";
static final String KEY_SATE = "day_sat_evn";

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Creating new HashMap
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Context context;

public LoadScheduleAsyncTask(Context ctxt){
    dba=new DBAdapter(ctxt);
    context=ctxt;
}

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 **/
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Updating Data ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * getting Schedule XML
 **/
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_SUNM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUNM));
        map.put(KEY_SUNE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SUNE));
        map.put(KEY_MONM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MONM));
        map.put(KEY_MONE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MONE));
        map.put(KEY_TUEM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TUEM));
        map.put(KEY_TUEE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TUEE));
        map.put(KEY_WEDM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_WEDM));
        map.put(KEY_WEDE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_WEDE));
        map.put(KEY_THUM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUM));
        map.put(KEY_THUE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUE));
        map.put(KEY_FRIM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FRIM));
        map.put(KEY_FRIE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FRIE));
        map.put(KEY_SATM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SATM));
        map.put(KEY_SATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_SATE));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         **/
        String group_id = map.get(KEY_NAME);
        String sunm = map.get(KEY_SUNM);
        String sune = map.get(KEY_SUNE);
        String monm = map.get(KEY_MONM);
        String mone = map.get(KEY_MONE);
        String tuem = map.get(KEY_TUEM);
        String tuee = map.get(KEY_TUEE);
        String wedm = map.get(KEY_WEDM);
        String wede = map.get(KEY_WEDE);
        String thum = map.get(KEY_THUM);
        String thue = map.get(KEY_THUE);
        String frim = map.get(KEY_FRIM);
        String frie = map.get(KEY_FRIE);
        String satm = map.get(KEY_SATM);
        String sate = map.get(KEY_SATE);

        try {
            dba.open();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        dba.insertData(group_id, sunm, sune, monm, mone, tuem, tuee, wedm,
                wede, thum, thue, frim, frie, satm, sate);
        dba.close();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all schedules
    pDialog.dismiss();

}
}
```

This answer is based on different approach than my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not registered your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Please register your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Whenever you create new activity you must register that one in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your own Constructor for `AndroidXMLParsingActivity`.

I dont think you should override the constructor. Also dont make your activity `Serializable`. Create a custom Serializable class which has fields with data you want to pass. Then pass this class, instead of your activity

Comment: can you please provide me some link or code or tutorial to do this. This has been a headache to me

Comment: create another class. you can refer any serializable class.